# Vue.js does not update HTML

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, es6-modules

I have the following `.html` file in my local Vue.js project (it's a simplified version):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Vue.js</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main>
            <div id="myElement">
                <div v-for="(properties, name) in list" v-bind:key="name">{{ name }}</div>
            </div>
        </main>

        <script type="module">
            import SomeClass from "./SomeClass.js";

            const myClass = new SomeClass();

            let app = new Vue({
                el: "#myElement",
                data: {
                    list: myClass.object
                },
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside the `<script type="module">` tag I import `SomeClass` which includes a property called `object`:

```
export default class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
        this.object = {
            name1: { ... },
            name2: { ... },
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

The issue here is that Vue.js reacts to changes in `object` (if I check it using `watch`) but it does not update my HTML:

`<div v-for"..." v-bind:key="...">...</div>`.

What can I do to make Vue.js update my HTML when new properties added to `object` / old properties updated?

Answer (score 0):

**Vue** has a method to add properties to items in the **data** attribute (so they keep reactivity). (More on this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

The snippet below may help you to see the method in action:

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.object = {
      name1: {
        name: 'name3'
      },
      name2: {
        name: 'name4'
      }
    }
  }
}

const myClass = new SomeClass()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    // transforming array for reactive display
    transformedObj() {
      const ret = []
      this.keyVal().forEach(e => {
        e.forEach(el => {
          ret.push(el)
        })
      })
      return ret

    }
  },
  data: {
    object: myClass.object
  },
  methods: {
    // transforming object for better display
    keyVal() {
      return Object.keys(this.object).map(e => {
        return Object.entries(this.object[e]).map(([k, v]) => {
          return `${k}: ${v}`
        })
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // add new property (reactive)
    Vue.set(this.object.name1, 'newProperty', '2')

    // or add new property (reactive)
    this.$set(this.object.name2, 'localNewProperty', 45)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, key) in transformedObj">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
  Object: {{transformedObj}}
</div>
```